# Minimum access rights for generating schema creation scripts

Tags: sql-server, permissions

In SQL Server 2008, it am running the "Generate SQL Server Scripts Wizard", attempting to create a script for all of the tables and views within a schema.

When I do this, I get an error:

> Property Text is not available for
>   DefaultConstraint
>   '[DF__aspnet_Ap__Appli__2A4B4B5E]'.
>   This property may not exist for this
>   object, or may not be retrievable due
>   to insufficient access rights. 
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo

What is the specific access right I need to complete this task?

Comment: Does granting VIEW DEFINITION work? I have the same issue but it's an outside vendor's database and it will be a BIG DEAL to get a permission changed. Most tables script successfully, btw. There are only a few where I get either: Property Text is not available for Check or Property Text is not available for DefaultConstraint

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately the Generate Scripts Wizard looks at sys.sql_expression_dependencies to find out what columns reference other columns. It does so even if you disable the exporting of foreign key constraints.
So you have to give the user that wants to use the wizard permissions to SELECT from sys.sql_expression_dependencies as well as VIEW (ANY) DEFINITION.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the VIEW DEFINITION permission.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175808.aspx